# How to create a T4 template and do it appear when i add new item in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, t4

Is it possible to create a T4 template and do it appear when i add new item in visual studio? For exemple, when i want to add i new class i press right button in my solution, or any directory and choose Add  > Add New Item, and now i select class, or interface...

I want to create T4 template to my specific Services, that i can have a ProductService, UserService, etc.. so, i want to do this: Right button in my solution, or any directory and choose Add  > Add New Item, and now i select Service that 'll generate the code based in my T4 template.

Or a way to do that similar when we add a New Controller in visual studio when we are working with asp.net mvc 3 project that appear the option "Add Controller", in my case would appear "Add Service".

Comment: I think you have to write a VisualStudio plugin for this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: More or less, "You can simply export your template as a Visual Studio template by selecting the Export Template... option from the File menu. This will run you through a wizard where you can name the template and even automatically import it into Visual Studio. Once you've gone through the wizard and imported it, your new template will appear under the node for your language of choice in the Add New Item dialog. – Dave Fancher."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add T4 templates to your project by selecting "Text File" from the add new item dialog and giving the file a .tt extension.  Overall, the editor support for T4 is pretty weak but there are a few extensions that help a bit.

Comment: I think that you don't understand my question. My objective isn't add new t4 template through visual studio. But create a t4 template, and make possible add this template that i create through visual studio like we do with class, interfaces, controllers (in asp.net mvc 3)...

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni - I'm sorry, you're right.  I didn't understand it correctly.

You can simply export your template as a Visual Studio template by selecting the Export Template... option from the File menu.  This will run you through a wizard where you can name the template and even automatically import it into Visual Studio.  Once you've gone through the wizard and imported it, your new template will appear under the node for your language of choice in the Add New Item dialog.

Comment: Almost. With this "Expost Template" i've to select a file in my project. And them the visual studio 'll create a file based in this file, but the problem is that i have to create a .cs file based in my .tt file using the Add New Item. And with the "Export Template" i have to select a .cs file to visual studio create a .cs file... =/

Comment: how can i delete a "Export Template" created?

Comment: You can just delete it from %userprofile%\documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates